# Create an EditText thats grouped together

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I want an EditText in android side by side and need a divider separating them just like the image below.
I haven't really thought of a proper way to do this whenever I think of it, I intend to use text Input layout with constraint layout and put them side by side but I don't think it'll work.
I have made some research online but couldn't get any help.

[image: edit text image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple EditText also. You just need to remove the underline from an EditText by using -

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
 android:background="@null"
```